# Combining 2 extended Activity for SMS Notification :D

Tags: android, notifications, sms

So, i want to create an app that can give it's user a notif everytime a SMS come.
My main problem is i get confuse how to combining my 2 Acitivites/classes. I extends BroadcastReceiver in SMSReceiver class so it can detect if any new SMS come, and i extends Activity in my SMSNotif class. The problem is I CAN'T EXTENDS MORE THAN 1 CLASS in each activity.

This is SMSReceiver class :

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Bundle bundle = arg1.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        }

        Toast.makeText(arg0, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    //Intent i = new Intent(SMSReceiver.this, SMSNotif.class);
}
```

}

And this is my SMSNotif class :

```
public class SMSNotif extends Activity{
static final int HELLO_ID = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    String tickerText = "Hello";
    //long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String contentTitle = "My notification";
    String contentText = "Hello World!";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SMSNotif.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

}
```

}

Again, my main question is : how to combine those Activities so i everytime the user get a new SMS, my app will show it's notif(not just a toast form SMSNotif).

Comment: HELLO ALL! :D
Sorry i forgot to say "Hello"
The system is not allowing me to edit my post :(

Comment: Isn't it easier to write code for notification in `SMSReceiver` too?

Comment: yes Sir, that's what i mean..but i don't know how to COMBINE it.. :D
Thanks he2

Comment: I mean why do you need activity? Just raise notification in receiver.

Comment: But to use NotificationManager and Intent i need to extends Activity..while in SMSReceiver i need to extends BroadcastReceiver..we can't extends 2 superclass...that's why i got confuse :D

Comment: You do not need extends `Activity` - you need only `Context`, witch you have in params of `onReceive()` in broadcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trick to solve your problem:

Make the BroadcastReceiver-class local to the Activity-class. This way the receiver can do something in the activity

```
public class SMSNotif extends Activity{

    class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            ...
            someActivityMetod("Hello world from receiver");
        }

    }

    void someActivityMetod(String message)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

you also have to (un-)register the receiver in the activities-code

```
public class SMSNotif extends Activity{

            BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = null;



    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {

        if (myReceiver != null)
        {
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
            myReceiver = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (myReceiver == null)
        {
            myReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("Some.Action.Code");
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
BTW, i get confuse in your 2nd code..
You use onPause and onResume, but where is the onCreate?is it after onResume?
Sorry i'm a beginner and i never use nested class like that :D

Comment: Btw, is there any better way than create a nested class like that Sir?
Thank you very much! :D

Comment: hello, you still need the onOnCreate. the onPause and onResume are necessary because the activity should only receive if running and visible

Comment: Btw, what do you mean in this line :  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("Some.Action.Code"); :D

Comment: see xml-docu for `<intent-filter><action>`

Comment: Thanks, Sir if you have time please  go to here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465434/using-2-nested-class-to-get-notification-from-new-sms-d
I already filter my manifest there...i also nested both Class in my manifest.. :D
Thanks