# Using 2 nested Class to get notification from new SMS :D

Tags: android, notifications, sms

I already asked a question here :
[combining-2-extended-activity-for-sms-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445866/combining-2-extended-activity-for-sms-notification-d)

And now i get a new problem :D

So i already make a nested Class like this :

```
public class SMSNotif extends Activity{
static final int HELLO_ID = 1;
BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = null;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bundle bundle = arg1.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
            }

            Toast.makeText(arg0, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //Intent i = new Intent(SMSReceiver.this, SMSNotif.class);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    String tickerText = "Hello";
    //long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String contentTitle = "My notification";
    String contentText = "Hello World!";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SMSNotif.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(myReceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        myReceiver = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    if(myReceiver == null){
        myReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

}

And my MANIFEST is like this :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SMSNotif"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </activity>
```

The problem is, **my app can't detect any new SMS now**...
Where is my mistake?is it in my manifest?
I already tried changing my codes but i still can't solve my problem...
So the question is :
**Can you help me so my app can detect new SMS and make a notification everytime new SMS comes?**
Thank you very much! :D
And sory if i made some mistakes, English is not my native languange :)
**I have an Idea : I tried to reverse the Class, so SMSReceiver will be the outer one and SMSNotif will be inside it...is it possible?(i tried it, and i got some errors) I think by inverse it the BroadcastReceiver will be able to detect new SMS..is it true?**

Comment: LOL, why is everytime i typed "Hello All" in my first sentence it's always dissapeared? :P

Comment: Yes, that happens to me too. Don't know why, they probably want to cut out all the crap :)

Comment: wkwkwkkwkw :D
It's kinda funny for me, i think it's not polite to ask without say "hello" first :D

Comment: @BlazeTama The Stack Overflow community has decided that greetings such as "hello" or "hi" and closings such as "Thanks" or "Thanks in advance" are unnecessary and so they are automatically removed when you post. You can read more about this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/148445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify that your receiver is in inner class in manifest.

```
     <activity
            android:name=".SMSNotif"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

 <receiver android:name="your.package.name.SMSNotif$SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The Receiver should not be in activity.

and your inner class SMSReceiver should be static

EDITED
If you want to just show the notification then Activity is not Required.

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final int HELLO_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bundle bundle = arg1.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
            }

            Toast.makeText(arg0, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) arg0
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            String tickerText = "Hello";
            // long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Notification notification = new Notification(
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText,
                    System.currentTimeMillis());

            // Context context = getApplicationContext();
            String contentTitle = "My notification";
            String contentText = "Hello World!";
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(arg0, SMSNotif.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, contentTitle, contentText,
                    contentIntent);
            notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
            mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir!
I have tried it, but it's still not working..i think maybe i made some mistakes in my Java code? :D

Comment: Is your SMSReceiver class static and have u added this permission android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS

Comment: yes Sir, i already add static keyword to my SMSReceiver class :D

Comment: FINALLY... it takes one week to solve this!
Thank you Sir! :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will solve your problem or not,but I think,you should try making following changes to your manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SMSNotif"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >        
</activity>
<receiver android:name="com.your.path.SMSNotif$SMSReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I hope,it will solve your problem.Because the broadcast receiver is inner class of SMSNotif class so you will have to give full path along with ActivityName$RecevierName as i shown above.

**EDIT :**

I have added  to intent-filter tag(see in above code).this will notify your app before it will notify android os for new sms.

Comment: Thank you :D
But what do you mean in this line : SMSNotif$SMSReceiver
:D

Comment: Yes...It is what you need to give as name of receiver as it is inner class of SMSNotif class

Comment: Why do you take your receiver class as inner class of SMSNotif? is it really needed for your app? because general scenario is,taking a separate receiver class and code in onReceive() there,whatever you want to do when a new sms arrives!

Comment: @BlazeTama: please see my edit in answer.I think,this is only what you miss!

Comment: Still not working...my app still can't "catch" any new SMS :D
Maybe the mistake is in my Java code Sir?
Thank you very much! :D